# Seeking Atlanta's limits shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states, borders

I need a shapefile of the limits of the city of Atlanta, USA.

Comment: If you have looked elsewhere unsuccessfully, then it may be worth researching/asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchamge.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Mapzen's metro extracts for Atlanta](https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/#atlanta-georgia). They use OSM data and I believe they've also imported Fulton County's data into it.

They also have different formats in case you need something other then shapefile

Answer (score 0):

Fulton County has GIS data available. If you cannot access the data for download on their GIS website, give their GIS department a call/email and ask if they have an FTP site or other means to download the data.

Comment: Here's Fulton County GIS portal:
http://share.myfultoncountyga.us:8080/geoportal/catalog/search/browse/browse.page